# Most computationally efficient method to get the rest of the array of a slice in numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy

For a numpy array

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

You can get a slice using something like `a[3:6]`

But what about getting the rest of the slice? What is the most computationally efficient method for this? So something like `a[:3, 6:]`.

The best I can come up with is to use a concatenate.

```
np.concatenate([a[:3], a[6:]], axis=0)
```

I am wondering if this is the best method, as I will be doing millions of these operations for a data processing pipeline.

Comment: There is `np.delete(a, slice(3, 6))` specifically designed for that, but it is slower. Note that `axis=0` is not needed here and slower. You can also use a tuple instead of a list: `np.concatenate((a[:3], a[6:]))`. "*I will be doing millions of these operations for a data processing pipeline*" THis is the actual problem: all these methods are slow because of of the Numpy interface overhead and a mandatory array creation + copies. If you want the process to be faster, then please do not do that or be prepared to pay >95% of the time of pure overheads. Can you describe the overall process?

Comment: Thanks. I am doing text processing for a machine learning training pipeline where a random sample of text is used to predict the rest of the sample. The text is converted to integers, and split into two. So `a[3:6]` would be the first passage from the text, and np.concatenate([a[:3], a[6:]]) would be the rest of the text. These two are inputs into the model.

Comment: @JérômeRichard , some more details, I'm also doing these in batched of 512. So it's actually a 2D array I'm working it, I used only 1d for the example. At first I was thinking of converting to a python list, doing the concatenations, and then converting back to numpy, but I don't think python lists supports doing operations for 2d lists, eg a2d[:, :3] + a2d[:, 3,:]

Comment: I advise you to use a lower-level language like C/C++ to do that (possibly Cython). This will be far more efficient. List will not be faster for that, unless the list is very small but it will be a pain for the 2D case (and not much better in the end).

Comment: I would propose to alter the array in the question to something that is closer to the dimension of your actual application, e.g. using `np.arange` or `np.mgrid`. Not only does the total length of the first axis matter, but also the ratio between the first and the second axis. While @7shoe's answer is true for your test-case, `np._r` outperforms all other methods **by a factor of 10** when I try it on a larger array of shape `1000 x 100 x 10 x 3`, where I slice over axis 0.

Comment: I wonder if I would need to make a new stack overflow question, but a size more closer to my application would be 52 rows, each with an array length of 1000

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems to be the most efficient one since it is more than 2x faster than the next best thing.

```py
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

%timeit -n 100000 np.concatenate([a[:3], a[6:]], axis=0)

%timeit -n 100000 np.delete(a, slice(3, 6))

%timeit -n 100000 a[np.r_[:3,6:]]

>2.03 µs ± 75.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
>4.61 µs ± 146 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
>11 µs ± 350 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

However, the real question is if these operations (complement set of slice/deletion) need to be applied consecutively. Otherwise, you could aggregate the indices via set operations and slice the compliment a single time in the end to obtain the proper NumPy array.

Answer (score 0):

I find declaring an empty array and filling it up seems to be very slightly better than using concat . As André mentioned in their comment this will vary based on the shape.

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

def testing123():
    new = np.zeros(6, dtype=int)
    new[:3] = a[0:3]
    new[3:] = a[6:]
    return new
```

`%timeit -n 100000 np.concatenate([a[:3], a[6:]], axis=0)`

100000 loops, best of 5: 2.18 µs per loop

`%timeit -n 100000 np.delete(a, slice(3, 6))`

100000 loops, best of 5: 6.11 µs per loop

`%timeit -n 100000 a[np.r_[:3,6:]]`

100000 loops, best of 5: 16.4 µs per loop

`%timeit -n 100000 testing123()`

100000 loops, best of 5: 2.01 µs per loop

```
a = np.arange(10_000)

def testing123():
    new = np.empty(5000, dtype=int)
    new[:2500] = a[:2500]
    new[2500:] = a[7500:]
    return new
```

`%timeit -n 100000 np.concatenate([a[:2500], a[7500:]], axis=0)`

100000 loops, best of 5: 3.99 µs per loop

`%timeit -n 100000 np.delete(a, slice(2500, 7500))`

100000 loops, best of 5: 7.76 µs per loop

`%timeit -n 100000 a[np.r_[:2500,7500:]]`

100000 loops, best of 5: 47.3 µs per loop

`%timeit -n 100000 testing123()`

100000 loops, best of 5: 3.61 µs per loop